# Query nested JSON objects

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, dom

I'm brand new to javascript and json and can't find any examples that explain how to get nested json objects.

This works great:

```
var someJson={"name":"spuder"};
alert(someJson.name);
//alert shows spuder
```

This returns undefined:

```
//This is the json from the stream I am reading
var someJson={"name":"spuder","car":[{"model":"ford","year":"2000"}] };
alert(?????);
```

how do you return spuders car model or car year?

```
alert(someJson.car.model); //doesn't work..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created your `car` as an array.  To get the model of the first car in the array:

```
alert(someJson.car[0].model);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YUrRg/

Comment: Aha! you're right (face palm) , thanks so much. That is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You were creating an array instead of an object in your someJson object. Further, you had an apostrophe beginning the year 2000 but ending it with a quotation mark.

```
var someJson={"name":"spuder","car":{"model":"ford","year":"2000"}};
alert(someJson.car.model);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I corrected the question. I'm still looking for what to put in the alert()